# Python 3: Nested while loops based time

Tags: python, time, while-loop, nested

I am trying to run two `while` loops based on an input condition. In this example, that is taken out and replaced by a `1 == 0` so that `0` can be changed back and forth for testing. Once selected, each `while` loop should run for 10 seconds and then the input condition checked (replaced by `1 == 0`) again.

The problem appears to be in the time comparison, since it never evaluates correctly. What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time 
import os
import bellmod
while True:
    starttime = time.time()
    print("Start time   " + str(starttime)) #Time check
    elapsedtime = 0 #Reset elasped time to 0 for each loop iteration.
    if 1 == 0: #Change this to run either loop. See if remote or local has precidence. 
        while(elapsedtime < 10):
            print("Inside remote while  " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) #Time check
        elapsedtime = time.time() - starttime #Calculate elasped time.
    else:
        elapsedtime = 0
        while(elapsedtime < 10):
            print("inside bottom of local while  " + str(int(time.time() - starttime))) #Time check
        elapsedtime = time.time() - starttime #Calculate elasped time.
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use `time.sleep(10)` to wait ten seconds?

Comment: @hoefling: then you can't do anything else.

Comment: Look closely at your indentation. When do you think `elapsedtime` is updated?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: oh, I see - sleeping would mean no prints while sleeping...

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `while` loops are endless, because `elapsedtime` is *never* updated:

```
while(elapsedtime < 10):
    print("inside bottom of local while  " + str(int(time.time() - starttime))) #Time check
elapsedtime = time.time() - starttime #Calculate elasped time.
```

`elapsedtime` is updated *after* the `while` loop ends, but that is never reached.

You need to fix your indentation so `elapsedtime` is calculated *each loop iteration*:

```
while(elapsedtime < 10):
    print("inside bottom of local while  " + str(int(time.time() - starttime))) #Time check
    elapsedtime = time.time() - starttime #Calculate elasped time.
```

Note that `while` is not a function. Using `(...)` groups the test expression, but is not needed or normally used. If you pass in values as separate arguments to `print()`, that takes care of including a separator and conversion to string for you:

```
while elapsedtime < 10:
    print("inside bottom of local while", int(time.time() - starttime))
    elapsedtime = time.time() - starttime
```

If you don't need to use `elapsedtime` in the loop, just inline the calculation:

```
while time.time() - starttime < 10:
    print("inside bottom of local while", int(time.time() - starttime))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't change `elapsedtime` inside the loop ... it's stuck at 0.
Indent the last line:

```
if 1 == 0: #Change this to run either loop. See if remote or local has precidence. 
    while(elapsedtime < 10):
        print("Inside remote while  " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) #Time check
        elapsedtime = time.time() - starttime #Calculate elasped time.
else:
    elapsedtime = 0
    while(elapsedtime < 10):
        print("inside bottom of local while  " + str(int(time.time() - starttime))) #Time check
        elapsedtime = time.time() - starttime #Calculate elasped time.
```

Comment: Yes the indentation was the problem,